# Cardinality of a subset of $S_{p-1}$.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, modular-arithmetic, symmetric-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $S_{p-1}$ the symmetric group of degree $p-1$. Let's consider the subset:
$$X:=\{\sigma\in S_{p-1}\mid P(1)\wedge P(2)\wedge P(3)\}$$
where:

- $P(1)$: $\sigma(i)\ne i$ for every $i=1,\dots,p-1$;
- $P(2)$: $\left|\sigma\right|\mid p-1$;
- $P(3)$: if $\sigma=(i_{11}\dots i_{1s_1})\dots(i_{r1}\dots i_{rs_r})$ is the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$, then $\forall j=1,\dots,r$:
  $$\sum_{k=1}^{s_j}i_{jk}\equiv 0\pmod p \tag 1$$

So, in particular, every $(p-1)$-cycle lays in $X$. On the other hand, if $\sigma\in X$ is not a $(p-1)$-cycle, then its cycle structure $(l_1,\dots,l_r)$ is such that $l_1+\dots+l_r=p-1$, with every cycle's length $2\le l_j\le\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(l_1,\dots,l_r)\mid p-1$. For instance, if $p=7$, then elements of $X$ are, *e.g.*: $\sigma=(123456)$, $\sigma=(16)(25)(34)$, $\sigma=(124)(356)$.

So, my question is: what's the cardinality of $X$, for a given $p$?

---

**Edit**. I had conjectured that the disjoint cycles would have all be of the same length, but $\sigma=(1,12)(2,11)(3,10)(49)(5678)$ is a counterexample for $p=13$.

**Edit#2**. The connection between the set $X$ and $\Bbb Z_p^*$, recalled by @kabenyuk's comment, was expected actually, considered the context where this question popped up, namely: Let's assume to be known that $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)\right|=p-1$; if we set $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)=\{Id_{C_p},\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_{p-2}\}$, then it turns out that every $\varphi_i$ is of the form:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi_i(1)&=1 \\
\varphi_i(a^j)&=a^{\sigma_i(j)}
\end{alignat}
***where*** $\pmb{\sigma_i\in X}$. My question here was meant as an intermediate step to finally prove that some of the $p-2$ permutations $\sigma_i\in X$ *must be* a $(p-1)$-cycle, so as to have a "$\Bbb Z_p^*$-free" proof of $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)\cong C_{p-1}$. But I see that this result seems really inseparable from the notion of $\Bbb Z_p^*$.

Comment: If you include trivial cycles in the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ in $P(3)$, then $P(1)$ is redundant (though it's fine to keep it to avoid doubt). Such permutations can equivalently be characterized as partitions of the set $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ for which the size of each part is a divisor of $p-1$, and the sum over each part is a multiple of $p$. Interesting question!

Comment: For $p=13$ there is also this $\sigma=(1,12)(2,3,8)(5,10,11)(4,6,7,9)$. By the way, new permutations with the same cyclic structure can be obtained from the given one by multiplying by $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small GAP program to determine the list of elements satisfying the condition (not listing all $p-1$-cycles):

```
Condition:=function(p)
local sn,dom,cl,set,i,j,z,dc,a,cnt,orb;
  dom:=[1..p-1];
  # Z_p* action
  z:=Group(PermList(List(dom,x->Int(Z(p)*x))));
  sn:=SymmetricGroup(p-1);
  cl:=ConjugacyClasses(sn);
  cl:=Filtered(cl,x->((p-1) mod Order(Representative(x))=0)
    and ForAll(dom,y->y^Representative(x)<>y));
  set:=[];
  for i in cl do
    dc:=DoubleCosetRepsAndSizes(sn,Centralizer(i),z);
    Print("Testing ",Size(i)," Elements, ",Length(dc)," double cosets\n");
    cnt:=0;
    for j in dc do
      a:=Representative(i)^j[1];
      if ForAll(Cycles(a,dom),c->Sum(c) mod p=0) then
        orb:=Orbit(z,a);
        cnt:=cnt+1;
        Append(set,orb);
      fi;
    od;
    if cnt>0 then
      Print("Type ",Representative(i)," gives ",cnt," solutions\n",
        "e.g. ",set[Length(set)],"\n");
    fi;
  od;
  return set;
end;
```

and we get solutions for primes: $p=2:0$, $p=3:1=2!+0$, $p=5:7=3!+1$, $p=7:125=5!+5$, $p=11:369217=9!+6337$, $p=13: 40550519=11!+633719$.

Note that for these primes *every* partition satisfying conditions 1 and 2 gives rise to solutions for condition 3.

Comment: If I may add a side-question: what if in addition the following "$P(4)$" sets in? $P(4)$: $\sigma$ is of the form $\sigma(k)=(p-k)c$, for some $c\in\{1,\dots,p-2\}$. If this isn't so easy to implement in the GAP code, no problem and forget it.

Comment: Of course I meant $\sigma(k)=(p-k)c\pmod p$.